# Change a dropdown depending on another dropdown

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a three select dropdowns that represent a persons birthday. I'm taking into consideration that there are 4 months with 30 days, 7 with 31 ,and 1 with 28 or 29 depending if it's a leap year or not. I would like the days dropdown to show the number of days depending on which month is chosen in the month dropdown. Here's what I have now.

Here's the html for the select

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Birthday validation</title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="birthday_drop.js"></script>

<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet />
</head>
<body>
<h2>Birthday</h2>
<fieldset class="birthday-picker">
<select class="birth-month" name="birth[month]"><option>Month</option></select>
<select class="birth-day" name="birth[day]"><option>Day</option></select>
<select class="birth-year" name="birth[year]"><option>Year</option></select>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the jquery that populates the dropdowns and my attempt to use the change function

```
/**
* Created by Eric Evans on 8/19/14.
*/

$(document).ready(function(){
var months =      ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'];

for(i=0; i < months.length; i++){
    $("<option value=' + months[i] + '>" + months[i] + "</option>").appendTo('.birth-month');

}
for(i=0; i <= 31; i++){
    $("<option value=' + i + '>" + i + "</option>").appendTo('.birth-day');
}

var myYear = new Date().getFullYear();
for(i=myYear; i >= 1950; i--){
    $("<option value=' + i + '>" + i + "</option>").appendTo('.birth-year');
}

$('.birth-month').change(function(){
   if($(this).val() == 'April'){
       for(i=0; i <= 30; i++){
           $("<option value=' + i + '>" + i + "</option>").appendTo('.birth-day');
       }
   }
});

});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Don't like people 65 and older?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would really consider using a jQuery datepicker or the like, and just turn on the changeYear and changeMonth features... but in either case, you *can* do something like this (drawback is that if you change the day first, it will erase that when you choose a month or year, though I suppose you could store the variable for the day, and reset it to that value after, if the value is present in that month):

```
function UpdateDays(){
    var cYear = $('select.birth-year').val();
    if(cYear != "Year"){
        var cMonth = $('.birth-month').val();
        if(cMonth != "Month"){
            $('.birth-day').html("<option>Day</option>");
            for(i=1; i <= new Date(cYear,cMonth,0).getDate(); i++){
                $("<option value=' + i + '>" + i + "</option>").appendTo('.birth-day');
            }
        }
    }
}
$('.birth-month,birth-year').change(function(){
    UpdateDays();
});
```

You do first have to correct the + i + value issue (you are assigning "+ i +" as the value, instead of ending the opening quotes first '" + i + "'), then you would either have to change the month value variable to a number, or use the array to find what number the month is (so you can pass it to the Date() method).

It's all working here if you want to check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/fuczrg03/2/

Comment: I just looked at the fiddle and it works, just I have to select year first, then month, before the days select populates right. Is there a reason why?

Comment: If you want to account for leap years you would need to know both before knowing how many days are in the month. Otherwise, you could pull the amount of days from an array like the months, then if the user selects a month first change it if the year is a leap year.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with Date objects

To get the number of days for a given year and month, you can use the below code

```
var startMonth = new Date(year, month, 1);
var endMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 1);
var daysInGivenMonth = (endMonth - startMonth) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```

Now the number of days in the month for a particular year will be assigned to daysInGivenMonth. You can use a for loop starting from 1 to <= daysInGivenMonth and populate your days drop down.